# All menu is not displayed

Tags: php

There are 4 sub menus in "menu" button which are drinks, main, appetizers and desserts. When users click drinks, they will be directed to drinks and the same when they go other sub menu buttons. But I want to display all menu when users click "menu" button. I know I have to use "else" but the menu does not display at all.

menu.php

```
<div class="products">
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
//current URL of the Page. basket_update.php redirects back to this URL
$current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE MenuTypeID = ".$_GET['id']);
$currency = '$';

if ($results) { 

    //fetch results set as object and output HTML
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {
        echo '<div class="product">'; 
        echo '<form method="post" action="basket_update.php">';
        echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="'.$obj->MenuPicture.'" /></div>';
        echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'.$obj->MenuName.'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->MenuDescription.'</div>';
        echo '<div class="product-info">';
        echo 'Price: '.$currency.$obj->MenuPrice.' | ';
        echo 'Qty <input type="text" name="menu_qty" value="1" size="1" />';
        echo '<button class="add_to_basket">Add To Basket</button>';
        echo '</div></div>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="MenuID" value="'.$obj->MenuID.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

?>
<?php 
}else{
       $query2 = "SELECT * FROM Menu";
       $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    }
?>

</div>
```

Comment: **WARNING:** You're exposing your database to an [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Ensure you validate and sanitize all user input. ([binding parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) too)

Comment: In your first query, you use menu as table name. But in second query it look as Menu ?

Comment: is the name of table case sensitive? @vural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<div class="products">
<?php

 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE MenuTypeID = ".$_GET['id']);
 }
 else{
 $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menu");
 }
  //current URL of the Page. basket_update.php redirects back to this URL
  $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);


 $currency = '$';

if ($results) { 

//fetch results set as object and output HTML
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
    echo '<div class="product">'; 
    echo '<form method="post" action="basket_update.php">';
    echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="'.$obj->MenuPicture.'" /></div>';
    echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'.$obj->MenuName.'</h3>';
    echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->MenuDescription.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="product-info">';
    echo 'Price: '.$currency.$obj->MenuPrice.' | ';
    echo 'Qty <input type="text" name="menu_qty" value="1" size="1" />';
    echo '<button class="add_to_basket">Add To Basket</button>';
    echo '</div></div>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="MenuID" value="'.$obj->MenuID.'" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed?

Comment: If there is a value in $_GET['id'], then retrieve the products in that particular category. Otherwise select all the products.